# How to create a series of nodes in AEM

Tags: aem, jcr

I want to create a series of nodes like parentProduct/subCategory1/subCategory2/subCategory3/subCategory4 inside /var/temp location. I tried to use *addNode()* method of Node class and *createPath()* method of JcrUtil class but both did not work. *addNode()* method just creates only one immediate node(ex, parentProduct) but it is creating second level onwards.

Is there any API available that can create a series of nodes, ex-parentProduct/subCategory1/subCategory2/subCategory3/subCategory4?

```
protected final void doGet(final SlingHttpServletRequest request, final SlingHttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException {
        final Session session;
        final ResourceResolver resourceResolver = request.getResourceResolver();
        session = resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class);
        long count = 0;
        final String path = "/var/temp";
        final PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {

            if (session.nodeExists(path)) {
                Node jcrNode = session.getNode(path);
                jcrNode.addNode("parentProduct/subCategory1/subCategory2/subCategory3/subCategory4");
                //jcrNode.addNode("parentProduct");
                //JcrUtil.createPath("parentProduct/subCategory1/subCategory2/subCategory3/subCategory4",JcrConstants.NT_UNSTRUCTURED, session);

            }
            session.save();

        } catch (ItemExistsException ex) {
            LOG.error("ItemExistsException", ex);
        } catch (RepositoryException exp) {
            LOG.error("RepositoryException", exp);
        } finally {
            if (session != null) {
                session.logout();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more than one way to do it. For example,

```java
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceUtil;
import org.apache.jackrabbit.JcrConstants;

String path = "/var/temp/parentProduct/subCategory1/subCategory2/subCategory3/subCategory4";
Resource subCategory4 = ResourceUtil.getOrCreateResource(
        resourceResolver, 
        path,                         // The full path to be created 
        JcrConstants.NT_UNSTRUCTURED, // resource type of the final resource to create
        JcrConstants.NT_UNSTRUCTURED, // resource type of all intermediate resources
        true                          // save  chnages
        );
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Tried with above code but the node is not created. I think we need to save the subCategory4.